# Router with ethernet ports + can use my mobile sim card

Tags: networking, router, internet

I need a backup for my internet service provider.

It seems what I need is a "drop-in" replacement router I can insert physical at the same place where my ISP router is located.

The idea is if my ISP is down (e.g. some main cable been capped somewhere and service will take 3 days) I can simply replace the router with one that gets it internet from my mobile phone / celluar, so I can still do basic work, email etc.

My current router has 4 ethernet LAN ports which each are connected to a switch which again services other switches, devices, work computers etc. I would like my "drop-in" solution to offer the same.

I imagine such a celluar router would either

- Take a sim card
- Connect with USB with phone (not sure this would work with most Android / iOS phones as I don't think they offer internet sharing this way)

But what is this kind of router called? When I look at my local hardware dealers online, it seems most "SIM routers" (?) are only WIFI - I want to continue using my cabled setup. However, I have a small hope that I may be searching for the wrong terms...

Comment: @DavidPostill The advice is "instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs". From the very beginning the OP asks "what is this kind of router called?" because of "a small hope that I may be searching for the wrong terms". Isn't this asking how to find out?

Comment: There isn't a special term for them.  They are advertised as `3G/4G`, there are numerous brands that, have 3G/4G routers.

Comment: I’m not an expert on this, but it seems like “cellular modem” might be a good starting point.  [A Google search for “cellular modem with Ethernet ports”](https://www.google.com/search?q=cellular+modem+with+ethernet+ports) gets over a million hits, although I don’t know how many of them are really what you want.

Comment: Both the answers received so far are very interesting and will most likely solve my problem. I will return and accept an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

You just need any cellular ethernet router... It sounds like you are looking at hotspot/mifi type devices.

I would also recommend looking up some buzzwords such as "IoT Gateway", "M2M router" or similar.

I personally buy in England in bulk some tiny ~£60 3G routers that work wonders.

I'm not entirely understanding your needs, but, if your current router doesn't support failover, you have a few options:

1. Most M2M routers allow for cellular failover - if you aren't using anything "advanced" in your current router (BGP/IPSEC/other site to site/MPLS or more), you can use the cellular router as your "main" router, and then have your existing one setup as primary so that it only uses cellular when it is down.
2. Taking the above further, if your connection is one that is presented as ethernet, and you don't use any "advanced" feature, you may have luck just using the new router directly with your current ISP. (It is possible to get a cellular router with a modem, but, they are usually quite expensive).
3. finding a new standard modem/router that works with USB cellular sticks - there used to be loads of these, they seem to be a bit rarer these days.
4. If you are using "advanced" features, hopefully one of these that is supported is failover, in this case, stick the cellular router behind one interface.
5. Configure a standalone cellular router with the same IP details as your existing one (having non overlapping DHCP pools and same static IP for LAN), and simply doing a hard switch over.

In any instance, I take it you understand basic networking and may need to renumber/set non overlapping subnets and similar.

Anyway, I hope this helps and pushes you in the right direction - let me know if you need to know anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Netgear "wireless extender" that can connect to a wireless network, start its own wireless network, and has 4 ethernet ports on the back.

I can turn on my hotspot on my phone, connect to it using the extender, release/renew my DHCP address on my desktop (plugged into port on back of extender) and I'm off and running.

Your phone should be providing DHCP service, so the "best" way to do this if you aren't really good at networking (addressing, gateways, routing tables, DNS servers, etc) is to disconnect/power off the "real" router, fire up the extender in its place.  When DSL service returns, reverse.